# validating date if no value or not using for and if-else

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I have a problem, I wanted to check all persons who are present on a certain date range and absent if they didn't attend the party. **BUT THE PROBLEM IS** I'm unable to check all dates in a date range, so what is happening in my codes are

if one or more dates are == to row[date] it'll display all ***CHECK***

```
What happens on my code
#*****************************************#
Firstname      Day 1     Day 2    Day 3
Alex           CHECK     CHECK    CHECK 
Mori           ----      ----     -----
Sansha         CHECK     CHECK    CHECK 
#*****************************************#
```

And this is:

```
What I wanted to happen
1. Checks every date if the person attended or not
2. Display results 

#*****************************************#
Firstname      Day 1     Day 2    Day 3
Alex           ----      CHECK    CHECK 
Mori           ----      CHECK    -----
Sansha         CHECK     CHECK    -----
#*****************************************#
```

here are my code, this is very native php

```
For table header of the table, where date is looping continuously according to date range from $_POST 
    //******************************************************//

    $start_sub = new DateTime($_POST['start_date']);
    $end_sub = new DateTime($_POST['end_date']);

    $interval = $start_sub->diff($end_sub);
    $result = $interval->days;

    //*****************************************************//

for ($x=0; $x <= $result; $x++) { 
    echo "<th>";
    echo date('y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['start_date'].'+'.$x.'days'));
    echo "</th>";
}
```

This one is for the result that CHECKS and --- the value of who attended or didn't

```
for ($i=0; $i <= $result_from_date_interval; $i++) {#start of for loop

        if ($row['date'] >= date('y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['start_date'].'+'.$i.'days'))) {#start of if condition
            echo "<td> CHECK </td>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<td> ---- </td>";
        }#end of if else condition

    }#end of for loop
```

---

```
Here is my database -- 
#**************************#
count   user_id   first_name      date
  1       a1      Sansha       2017-11-25
  2       a2      Alex         2017-11-26 
  3       a3      Mori         2017-11-26
  4       a1      Sansha       2017-11-26
  5       a2      Alex         2017-11-27
#**************************#
```

I'm having a problem on the last for loop statement. I'm not very familiar with this kind of approach so if you could help me I'll be very much thankful.

Comment: Could you give us the data of your DB Table? (Content of $row)

Comment: @Marcus done editing

Comment: What is the Datatype of your column `date`?

Comment: It's actually timestamp but I only needed the date only for this part of the code @Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only problem is you date compare.
You make it this way:

```
if($row['date'] >= date('y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['start_date'].'+'.$i.'days')))
```

so if the `$row['date']` is **equal or greater** then you print the `CHECK`. If you use `==` (**equal**) it should work

```
if($row['date'] == date('y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['start_date'].'+'.$i.'days')))
```

**[EDIT]**

Change you compare to

```
if(date('y-m-d', $row['date']) == date('y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['start_date'].'+'.$i.'days')))
```

to compare only the date, not the time (witch is also stored in your timestamp-column)

Comment: If I do that all records will go "---" since > == < means exact value. 
Since the person from the database named "Alex" didn;t attend on 2017-11-25 then the result from > == < will be **all "---"** @Marcus

Comment: Then you have to change the compare. I will update my answer.